# How to write literal Javascript in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to add a member to an `HTMLElement`, in other words, I need to store data into an element. This is what I would like to achieve as if I am coding in [ScriptSharp](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp).

```
/** My method */
public DoIt(element: Element, obj: Object) {
  Literal("{0}.extended = {1}", element, obj); // This is not standard Typescript!
}
```

**In my example** ScriptSharp (a project to convert C# code into Javascript) provides a `Script.Literal` object that allows developers to write plain Javascript when a C# abstraction is not possible.

So that the Javascript output is:

```
// Probably Typescript will render it a bit differently, but basically
// this is what we get in the end...
var _doit = function(element, obj) {
  element.extended = obj;
};
```

How can I achieve this in Typescript? Or maybe I should handle this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any valid JavaScript is also valid TypeScript.
This means that you can write literal JS in any place in your code.

```
var _doit = function(element, obj) {
  element.extended = obj;
};
```

This is valid JS **and** TS.

However, since you use TypeScript, you may also want to use static typing with your code.
If you just add types to your code, it will compile correctly, but you'll get a semantic error:

```
var _doit = function(element:HTMLElement, obj) {
  element.extended = obj; // error: HTMLElement doesn't have property 'extended'
};
```

To prevent this error, you can notify the compiler that you intend to create a new property on `HTMLElement`:

```
interface HTMLElement {
  extended?: any;
}
```

Now the compiler knows that you have an (optional) property `extended` on `HTMLElement` and will compile without errors. You will also get code autocompletion on this property (and JSDoc if provided).

Comment: @Andry: yes, interfaces in TypeScript are [open-ended](https://github.com/teppeis/typescript-spec-md/blob/master/en/ch07.md#72-declaration-merging), their contents are combined.

Comment: This is amazing thing! Thanks, I like your approach because `any` is fine but with an extended interface we are still having a bit of consistency and we actually declare how we want to extend stuff :)

Comment: @zlumer: This is actually not quite true. Consider the following construction of JSON. This would work fine in Javascript but leads to problems when written in Typescript [(Online TS)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20blah%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%E2%80%82%E2%80%82key1%3A%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%E2%80%82%E2%80%82key2%3A%20'bar'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20blubb%20%3D%20%7Bblah%5B'key1'%5D%3A%20blah%5B'key2'%5D%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: @Tom `{blah['key1']: blah['key2']}` is NOT valid JS nor JSON. According to [ES5](https://es5.github.io/) spec, only **IdentifierName**, **StringLiteral** or **NumericLiteral** are allowed in object initializers. Like this: `{ foo: "identifier", 1:"numeric", "str":"string" }`

Comment: @zlumer thanks for clearing that up! Didn't have a look into the specs, my bad. The piece of code I remembered was a ruby hash, where this is possible. Got confused there and didn't double check.

Comment: This is not always true. Consider `if(!window.MAYBE_THIS_EXISTS) window.MAYBE_THIS_EXISTS = {};`

Comment: @KellyElton please elaborate what are you commenting on.

Comment: `Any valid JavaScript is also valid TypeScript. This means that you can write literal JS in any place in your code.` The following code is only valid in Javascript `if(!window.MAYBE_THIS_EXISTS) window.MAYBE_THIS_EXISTS = {};`

Comment: This is a perfectly valid Typescript code. It may give a `semantic error` (semantic errors don't prevent code from compiling to JavaScript, as opposed to syntactic errors), but only if `window.MAYBE_THIS_EXISTS` is not declared anywhere in the code.

Comment: I could not get that interface trick to work with Window class. Instead I extend and cast it to the derived class type.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
class Foo {
  public DoIt(element: Element, obj: Object) {
    var anyElement: any = element;
    anyElement.extended = obj;
  }
}
```

The problem (as you probably noticed) is that Element does not declare a property with the name extended, so TypeScript does its job and enforces the Element type. If you want to work around this, you can use the `any` type to do this.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Works great for me! This answer put an abrupt stop to my endless hours of scouring the internet.

Answer (score 2):

> Or maybe I should handle this problem in a different way?

If you want to completely break out of the compiler checking just have a standard `javascript` file. Note that if you want to use this *from typescript* you will have to tell typescript about it (using `ambient declarations`).

Personal Advice: Just use TypeScript.